# Ubuntu - VNC Error - something went wrong, connection is closed

Tags: xubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a docker container using ubuntu image. I am trying to connect to it using VNC viewer to run some automation. I was able to make a connection through vnc viewer, but after couple of hours the connection to the vnc viewer got dropped and I started getting an error - Something went wrong, connection is closed. The script and everything is working fine. There is a connection with the vnc server, just the screen connection got closed. Does any one have any idea of why that happened?